# AZCopy DateTime

Tags: azcopy

Having an issue downloading a SQL backup file from azure storage based on the shared snapshot datetime details.

I'm using the following string:

```
AzCopy.exe  /Source:https://ascentibackup.file.core.windows.net/sqlbackups/TICCSAZR-WSFC1%24TICCS%20Prod%20AG01/Postcode/FULL_COPY_ONLY/TICCSAZR-WSFC1%24TICCS%20Prod%20AG01_Postcode_FULL_COPY_ONLY_20200227_223325.bak?sharesnapshot=2020-02-29T05%3A02%3A24.0000000Z  /Dest:R:\Restore\gcfs /SourceKey: Key  /Pattern:TICCSAZR-WSFC1%24TICCS%20Prod%20AG01_Postcode_FULL_COPY_ONLY_20200227_223325.bak
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Seems irrelevant what database you are using as the question is entirely about azcopy. The type of file you are trying to download is irrelevant